# Why does opencv on Canopy downgrade numpy, scipy, and other packages when I try to install it?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, package, enthought, canopy

On my package manager for canopy, every time I try to download opencv it downgrades several other important packages. I am then not able to upgrade those same packages or run my code. How can I download opencv without downgrading my other packages?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided any version or platform information. But perhaps you are using an old Canopy version (current is 2.1.9), or perhaps you are using the subscriber-only "full" installer, which is only intended for airgapped or other non-updateable systems. Otherwise, the currently supported version of opencv is 3.2.0 (build 3.2.0-4) which depends on numpy 1.13.3, which is the currently supported version of numpy.